# How to pipe output from legacy commands in powershell?

Tags: command-line, powershell

I want to pipe the stdout from "legacy" commands into powershell, but I can't find the correct syntax. For example, here I want to get the last line output by `git tag`:

```
git tag | Get-Content -Tail 1
```

The above does not work, because `The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command`

How is this done? I hope I don't have to use an intermediate file.

Comment: `$var = (git tag)[-1]` or `$var = git tag | Select-Object -Last 1`

Comment: Thanks, I just used trial and error to figure out ` $(git tag).split()[-1]` 
I'm looking for a general answer for how to convert stdout into an object that Cmdlets will process. I'm now suspecting that the answer is "You Don't".
 
I wonder if the general approach should be to split the single-string output of legacy commands into an array of lines, and pass that array to Cmdlets .I'll try with some other Cmdlets and see if that is viable.

Comment: And BTW future reader, if you are using powershell, and you want the chronologically latest or earliest git tag for a repository, you can use
`$(git tag --sort=committerdate).split()[-1] ` to get the latest tag, and `$(git tag --sort=committerdate).split()[0]` to get the earliest.

Comment: The easiest way is to use `Import-Csv`/`ConvertFrom-Csv` followed by buidling a `[PSCustomObject]@{property='value'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that

```
git tag | Get-Content -Tail 1
```

gives the above error is that Get-Content is the wrong cmdlet for the intended result. You can't pipe *content* to `Get-Content`, only some of the parameters (by name):

```
Inputs
System.Int64, System.String[], System.Management.Automation.PSCredential

You can pipe the read count, total count, paths, or credentials to Get-Content.
```

As indicated in the answers by LotPings, the correct cmdlet is `Select-Object`. However, as other suggestions indicate (and contrary to the assertion by Charlweed), the output of legacy commands **IS** (typically) an array of strings (lines). This is why `(git tag)[-1]` gives the last line. However, this would not work if the legacy command produced only one line. In this case, the output is a single string, not an array of 1 string. and so `(git tag)[-1]` would return the last **character** of that line. To force the output to always be an array, use the "Array sub-expression operator" `@` as follows:

```
@(git tag)[-1]
```

I don't know the format of a line returned by `git tag` but in general `$(<some legacy command>).split()` would be wrong.
Firstly, the `$` is redundant. It is telling powershell to evaluate the contents of () as a pipe-line expression but the use of () on the command line, without the `$`, has the same meaning. `$()` is used within double-quoted (expandable) strings to insert the string value of an expression.
Secondly, use of `.split()` on the result of the legacy command can cause 1 of 2 effects. If the output is a single line then it is a single string and `.split()` is called. If it is an array of strings (multiple lines) then this causes powershell to perform a member enumeration (since `Array` has no split method). In both cases, the effect is the same as

```
git tag | foreach { $_.split() }
```

Invoking `.split()` results in a call to `String.Split(char[])`, passing in an empty array for the separator.

> Each element of separator defines a separate delimiter that consists of a single character. If the separator argument is null or contains no characters, the method treats white-space characters as the delimiters. White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard; they return true if they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace method.

The resulting output is every input line split up into individual words (as demarcated by white space).

While I suspect that CharlWeed has long since figured out what is happening, I include this description for those reading this question so that they aren't mislead.